# Best way to store multidimensional string arrays in android resources

Tags: android, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

I know this might have been asked some time, somewhere else, but I couldn't find a satisfying answer :/

Suppose I have some amount of static data for my android app. Each entry has a structure like

```
Item {
    firstValue;
    secondValue;
    List<SubItems> subItems;
}
SubItem {
    title;
    text;
}
```

What is the best way to store this 'Items' - in terms of size and performance?

My ideas so far:

1) some kind of xml structure:

```
<root>
    <Item>
        <firstValue/>
        <secondValue/>
        <list>
            <SubItem><title/><text/></SubItem>
            <SubItem><title/><text/></SubItem>
            <SubItem><title/><text/></SubItem>
        </list>
    </Item>
    <Item> ... </Item>
    ...
</root>
```

This would require some readers to parse the structure.

2) concatenated strings with different separators:

```
<string>firstValue # secondValue # title % text ## title % text ## ...
```

First split by '#', then split the third part by '##' to get SubItems and then split them by '%'.

Till now I used the second option, but the amount of text is getting bigger and I this concatenation seems to get out of control.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a pretty nice way to store string data.  There's even [handy online editors](http://jsoneditoronline.com/).
And Android even has a built-in [`JsonReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)!